# Can someone please explain what is protected override void?

Tags: c#

I am learning about xamarin in basic stage. All the function calls are done by 'protected override void'. So that anyone please help what is the use of it. How it differs from public void.

Comment: Have you heard of google.com?

Comment: This is early, "introduction to C#" information. Please find a book or other resource to learn the language.

Answer (score 11):

1. protected - access modifier (in C# you have public, protected, private, *internal*)
2. override - you override virtual method which was implemented scope above
3. void - return type of your method

Answer (score 3):

public - everyone can access this method.
protected - only inherited classes can access this method.